# Navbar toggler is displayed, but I click on it and it doesnt shows the navbar items

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to get a navbar with two items (a ngbdropdown and a link) and when I reduce the resolution the toggler is displayed, but I click on it and it doesn't do anything.

This is my html code: (Missing the nav tag at the end, I put it here but doesn't detect it).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-toggleable-md" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand ml-3 margin-items" href="#"><img src="../assets/GroupeRenault.png" alt="groupeRenault"></a>
    <button
        class="navbar-toggler collapsed"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-expanded="true"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" >
            <li class="nav-item mr-2 padding-items">
                    <a  style="color:#666" href="https://dda-localhost:4200/dashboard" >{{this.userLanguage}}</a>
                </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <div
                    ngbDropdown
                    class="d-inline-block"
                >
                    <button
                        class="bNombre"
                        id="dropdownForm1"
                        ngbDropdownToggle
                    >
                       {{this.userName}}
                    </button>
                    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownForm1">
                        <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="this.logout()">Logout</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please make this project in stackblitz so we can fetch issue easily.

Comment: Ok. I'll do it.

Comment: Sorry but its the first time I use stackblitz and i can't configure it properly. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1w7nyy

Comment: just add or remove class `show` on button click     for example  `[ngClass]="{'show': isNavbarMobile}"`  and on button click ` (click)="isNavbarMobile = !isNavbarMobile"` make sure you have intialised `isNavbarMobile= false` first

Comment: it's okay @JavirGallegosGarcía i was make an example for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-bootstrap-navbar just see and make it as per your requirement like you can change media query , css and etc just see this and get it. open the result in separate screen so you can see easily .

Comment: hope you will get your answer.

Comment: So much thanks, It works perfectly!! If u put it as answer I can mark it as the good one.

Comment: @PavanNagadiya Is it possible to make nav items appear in a side bar when screen resolution is reduced instead of appearing below the navbar?

Comment: yes but for that you have to write a lots of css mediaquery and javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the following changes, ie just add or remove class named  `show`  on button click

**component.ts**

```
 isNavbarMobile: boolean = false;
```

**component.html**

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-toggleable-md" role="navigation">
            <a class="navbar-brand ml-3 margin-items" href="#"><img src="../assets/GroupeRenault.png" alt="groupeRenault"></a>
            <button  (click)="isNavbarMobile = !isNavbarMobile" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{'show': isNavbarMobile}" id="navbarNavDropdown">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" >
                    <li class="nav-item mr-2 padding-items">
                            <a  style="color:#666" href="https://dda-localhost:4200/dashboard" >{{this.userLanguage}}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <div  ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" >
                            <button class="bNombre" id="dropdownForm1" ngbDropdownToggle >
                               {{this.userName}}
                            </button>
                            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownForm1">
                                <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="this.logout()">Logout</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
              </ul>
         </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: also make sure you set the `z-index: 999` for the navbar toggle button so that you can make sure that it is placed on top and is clickable

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it doesn't show the items under de button. It shows them at the left of the page but I guess that this is a css problem.

Comment: @JavirGallegosGarcía yes  you are right that depends on how you write your css, this is the default bootstrap behaviour of navbar